# Edit action no hace nada en automapper

Tags: mvc, asp.net-core, controller, automapper

Estoy usando Visual Studio 2019, .net core 3.1 y automapper. Mi acción Editar no edita el registro. He visto tutoriales, pero todos son solo una acción y necesito hacer un crud. Tomando como ejemplo una acción de edición habitual, he hecho esto:

```
public class CustomerCountriesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public CustomerCountriesController(ApplicationDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        // GET: CustomerCountries
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()        
        {
            //CustomerCountries customerCountry = new CustomerCountries();
            var customerCountry = await _context.CustomerCountries.ToListAsync();            
            List<CustomerCountriesDto> countries = _mapper.Map<List<CustomerCountries>, 
                                                    List<CustomerCountriesDto>>(await _context.CustomerCountries.ToListAsync());
         
            return View(countries);
        }

public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            
            var customerCountries = await _context.CustomerCountries.FindAsync(id);
            var model = _mapper.Map<CustomerCountries, CustomerCountriesDto>(customerCountries);

            if (customerCountries == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            

            return View(model);
            //return View(customerCountries);
        }

        // POST: CustomerCountries/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]        
        //public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, [Bind("CustomerCountry")] CustomerCountries customerCountries)
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string customerCountry, CustomerCountriesDto customerCountriesDto)
        {
            if (customerCountry != customerCountriesDto.CustomerCountry)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    var CustomerCountries = _mapper.Map<CustomerCountriesDto, CustomerCountries>(customerCountriesDto);                    
                    _context.Update(CustomerCountries);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();                    
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!CustomerCountriesExists(customerCountriesDto.CustomerCountry))                    
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(customerCountriesDto);
        }


public class AutoMapping : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapping()
        {
            CreateMap<CustomerCountries, CustomerCountriesDto>();
            CreateMap<CustomerCountriesDto, CustomerCountries>();
        }
    }

public class CustomerCountries
    {
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Longitud máxima para el país: 50")]
        public string CustomerCountry { get; set; }

        public ICollection<CustomerRegions> CustomerRegions { get; set; }
    }

public class CustomerCountriesDto
    {
        public string CustomerCountry { get; set; }
}
```

En startup

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
```

El ID de la tabla es CustomerCountry

¿Me pueden decir la forma correcta? Ya he leido varios posts, lo que encuentro son tutoriales sólo para hacer una parte del crud, no he encontrado un crud completo, es decir, con las acciones http post... en base a lo que se de .net core ensamblé esto pero no graba la modificación, he intentado varias formas pero no logro ensamblarlo correctamente

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la solución gracias a un desarrollador experimentado que me guió a través del problema y corrigió mi código de vez en cuando (eso es realmente ayudar). Resulta que estaba usando un campo como PK: CustomerCountry ... No estaba usando e Id, cuando cambié el modelo, ocurrió la actualización

```
var CustomerCountries = _mapper.Map<CustomerCountriesDto, CustomerCountries>(customerCountriesDto);
var country = _context.CustomerCountries.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == CustomerCountries.Id);
country.CustomerCountry = customerCountriesDto.CustomerCountry;
                        _context.Update(country);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```